# Can I view a Postgis Geometry Array in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, array

I've got an array of geometry as a column in a postgis database. Is it possible to view the data (even the n'th element?) in qgis?

Comment: Only idiots try to edit English, and in fact make it worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not directly.

However, you can create [a VIEW](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html) using some fancy SQL, which will open in QGIS. If this is a one-off, you can [SELECT INTO](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html) a new table instead by modifying the query.

Say you have a table `geo_arrays` with a `geoms` geometry array column type. Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW geo_parts AS
  SELECT
    row_number() OVER () AS gid,
    v.gid as old_gid,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY gid) part,
    geom
  FROM
    (SELECT gid, unnest(geoms) AS geom FROM geo_arrays) AS v
```

Which will give a new `gid` unique key required by most programs, as well as the old primary key and array part number (if these are useful). If the geometry arrays are heterogeneous (e.g., a mixture of POINT and LINESTRINGs), then in QGIS there will be a layer for each type.